# BizTalk Deployment Framework Solution Deployment Restarts all Host instances

Tags: biztalk, btdf

When I deploy my solution using BTDF, all Host instances are getting restarted while I need only 3 to restart for this BT App.

I have the 3 hosts identified in the SettingFileGenerator.xml file (SendHost, ReceiveHost and ProcessingHost) and here is the setting I have in Deployment.btdfproj file for this :

```
    <SkipHostInstancesRestart>False</SkipHostInstancesRestart>
<StartApplicationOnDeploy>True</StartApplicationOnDeploy>
<ItemGroup>
    <PropsFromEnvSettings Include="SsoAppUserGroup;SsoAppAdminGroup;SendHost;ReceiveHost;ProcessingHost"/>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <BizTalkHosts Include="$(SendHost);$(ReceiveHost);$(ProcessingHost)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Anything else I'm missing to prevent all Host instances from restarting?

Comment: @Samuel Liew This is NOT "professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration", this is part of creating a release package for a BizTalk application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the BTDF [documentation](http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_5/)

> **BizTalk Host names to restart**
>
> The BizTalkHosts ItemGroup is appropriate for the names of one or more BizTalk hosts that should be restarted during the deployment and undeployment processes.

```
<ItemGroup>   
 <BizTalkHosts Include="MyHostName" />    
</ItemGroup>
```

> Include attribute: BizTalk host name
> Repeating: 1 or more elements

So it should be

```
<ItemGroup>   
 <BizTalkHosts Include="SendHost" />    
 <BizTalkHosts Include="ReceiveHost" /> 
 <BizTalkHosts Include="ProcessingHost" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```